# Apache - Creating CSR resulting in SSL Certificate with no .key

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, windows-server-2016

I am brand new to creating a CSR manually in Apache (Windows server), as well as installing the resulting certificate.  However, here is what I have done.

First, I generated the CSR by using the following command...

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout [domainname].key -out [domainname].csr -config "C:\Apache24\conf\openssl.cnf"
```

then I stepped through and answered the prompts.  I did not enter anything for Passphrase, I simply hit enter and skipped it.  not sure if that is what caused the issue I'm having or not.

After the CSR was generated, I uploaded it to my SSL vendor and then downloaded the resulting certificate .zip file.  The .zip file though only contains 2 files.  One being a random string filename .crt and one being a bundle filename .crt file.  There is no .key file in the zip at all.

I then added the following lines to my VirtualHosts file in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/mydomain.com"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "c:\ssl\mydomain.com\randomstringfilename.crt"
    SSLCACertificateFile "c:\ssl\mydomain.com\bundlefilename.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to start Apache service, it bombs and I get the following in the error.log file.

```
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.096246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/ssl/mydomain.com/randomstringfilename.crt)
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key mydomain.com:443:0, check C:/ssl/mydomain.com/randomstringfilename.crt
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Nov 21 12:13:08.097246 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10496:tid 500] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with the fact that I do not have a private.key file to add to the VirtualHosts with SSLCertificateKeyFile statement, but I'm not sure because I've never done this before.

What do I need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> openssl req -new ... **-keyout [domainname].key** ...

When you ran that command that created the CSR, it created a key saved to `[domainname].key` hopefully  you still have it somewhere.  If not, just re-generate a new CSR, and re-key.  Most CAs will let you generate a new key/cert without any additional charges.  This time pay close attention to where your key and csr is saved to.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  I have the .key file and after adding it to my Virtual Hosts and restarting Apache - all works as expected!